How to configure the Remote Desktop Client?
I am using Remote Desktop to connect to a useful Windows 11 machine. I use Windows 11 myself. Sometimes, the connection is interrupted, and Remote Desktop tries to reconnect 5 times. I would like to increase the number of attempts to a bigger number (e.g. 20 or maybe infinity). I heard that in some previous versions it was bigger, and it is now controlled by the file default.rdp.
Where can I find this file?
I found some complaints on the Internet that it was once created annoyingly in my "documents" folder. I suppose this was "fixed" in later Windows versions, and they moved it somewhere, or maybe made it optional. Does Remote Desktop still create this file if it doesn't exist? Where should it be located?
Or is there a different way in which I must configure my Remote Desktop client?

Seems like Windows 10 2004 changed the retries limit to 5, where it was
previously 20.
This can be overridden in the file
C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Default.rdp
(or in your .rdp file) by adding:
AutoReconnect Max Retries:i:25

This will set the number of reconnection attempts to 25.

Default.rdp is a hidden file created in the user's Documents directory. This has been the case for a long time, as long as I can recall, probably going back to Windows XP. Microsoft's documentation notes this is still the case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc
The primary way to update this file is to open Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc) modify the settings in that application, and save the settings. You can, however, open it using Notepage or another text editor, to control settings that may not be apparent in the GUI.
